# How to write a PHP extension to work with the console program?

Tags: php, linux, debian

There is a console program for morphological analysis of text https://tech.yandex.ru/mystem/.

Work with the program from the console is simple:

```
./mystem -lwd in.txt out.txt
```

I need to carry out a morphological analysis of the text by means of PHP, use the exec () function is impossible.
The easiest way, using PHP to write text to a file, then using a bash script and cron to analyze and save into another file.

But I would like a more convenient option as a PHP function mystem (string, param).

Compile and install extensions I can, but do not know how to write them.
I think the problem is very simple, because maybe someone is faced with the decision of this problem is the "fish"?

Total my question is, Does anyone have a ready solution where you can change only the name of the console program and the expansion will be ready? Thank U!